# Tensorflow 2.8 error save model - UnboundLocalError with "logging_verbosity"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I'm working on building and testing a model found [here](https://github.com/Huiying-Li/Latent-Backdoor) to update it to Tensorflow 2, but after attempting to save the model with `tf.keras.Model.save(teacher,"saved_model/tea_model");` and received the following error on Google Colab Pro

```
<ipython-input-9-b823fb312e0f> in main()
--> 513     tf.keras.Model.save(teacher, "saved_model/tea_model");

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/autotrackable.py in _list_functions_for_serialization(self, unused_serialization_cache)
     99           functions[attribute_name] = attribute_value
    100     finally:
--> 101       logging.set_verbosity(logging_verbosity)
    102 
    103     return functions

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'logging_verbosity' referenced before assignment
```

I do have `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` as it was initially written in v1.14.0 and need to maintain the compatibility, but after attempting the [saving methods](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/saved_model) for both versions of Tensorflow I get the same error.

I can save the weights on the model, but would prefer the SavedModel format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to simply define `verbosity` in the flags I was using as such:

```
from tensorflow.python.platform import flags
...
flags.DEFINE_integer('verbosity', 0, 'Verbosity of the error messages')
```